# Non-inverting OP Amp supply

Tags: operational-amplifier, non-inverting

I want to amplify a voltage range (from 0.54 mV to 42 mV) in below circuit which the gain of the Op Amp is 10x, so the Vout will be (5.4 mV : 0.42 V) ..

and this Vout will be a Vin again in another non-inverting Op Amp to be amplified 10x so the final Vout will be (54 mV : 4.2 V)

**Question**
What's the Vdd that must be supplied to the Op Amps in both amplifying stages to get these Vouts --the Supply has to be 2.5 volts only--?

[image: Circuit]

Comment: That's very clear.. so in the 2nd stage where the maximum output will be 4.2v, the Op-amp can be supplied by 2.5 volts (let us assume 2.5v is above the minimum supply voltage), maybe this is a stupid question but I'm very new into op-amps

Comment: 0.54mV is below the input offset voltage of most opamps. Designing the circuit with the required accuracy is going to be challenging. Anyway, back on topic, why do you suggest the supply voltage should be 2.5V? Where does this figure come from?

Comment: Also, why two stages? Why not have one stage with a gain of -100?

Comment: First because the system going to run on a Li-ion battery which going to produce out 2.7v as a minimum discharging volts before it die & need to be charged .. Second no problem with using a gain of 100.. but I don't know much about op-amps and I think the output voltage is relative to the supply.

Comment: The supply voltage must be greater than the max output voltage you need plus some overhead specified in the opamp datasheet. So if you need 4.2V out, you can't supply only 2.5V. Does it answer the question?

Comment: 0.54mV is below the typical offset of most OpAmps. Do not expect miracles. While there are many OpAmps that can operate near their -Vdd (GND), a better approach being powered by a battery (and maybe isolated from the measured signal) could be to use a differential amplifier for a first stage.

Comment: Then, the most important sentence of your question: "the Supply *has to* be 2.5 volts only?" was very misleading. It should have been: "*Can* the supply be 2.5V only?"

Comment: There are Op Amps with very low input offset such as chopper stabilized and can have input voltage down to GND. You did not mention what bandwidth you need? Using two x10 stages could provide wider bandwidth if needed.

Answer (score 2):

To get an output voltage of 4.2V, your supply should be at least 5V.  The output of the opamp cannot be higher than its rail voltage (and you won't even get that much out, even with a rail-to-rail type).

Further, with an input voltage of 0.54mV, you are going to have no luck with such a simple circuit.  You will also need a negative supply with inputs that close to ground.